# Apache Solr Upgradation to latest version in existing Application

Tags: solr, upgrade, solr4

I have apache Solr 3.5 instance with my web application. I want to upgrade it to latest version so I have some queries -
1. What latest version is stable and ok to upgrade to?
2. If I have to upgrade is there any document/process steps to do so? if so Please share.

Thank you.
Devendra

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of Solr available is 4.4 as mentioned on the Solr site.
You can check the change log for the changes that might impact you.
As the lucene version would be upgraded as well, the index you have may not be valid and would require reindexing.
Quick way to check is just have the conf files copied and the index rebuilt with the latest version.
Also, check for the reference Configuration files available with the example and remodel your configuration accordingly as they would have been mdofied to take into account the changes for the latest version.